# Get registered users from my contact list using smack api android with ejabberd 17.1

Tags: android, chat, ejabberd, smack

I am creating a chat messenger using smack api on android with ejabberd server. Want to synchronize my contacts list. There may be several users on server do not want to fetch data for all. Just want to send a contact list to server and it should return those among list which are registered. Any idea how to do that? Using AbstractXMPPConnection for this purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such module or functionality in ejabberd server you have to develop custom module for this task. Your custom module will sync contact as you want. Following are the some useful links that guide you how to create custom ejabberd module-

https://metajack.im/2008/08/28/writing-ejabberd-modules-presence-storms/

http://happy.cat/blog/XMPP-Bots-ejabberd-mod-motion-2010-02-01-10-00.html

https://github.com/Mingism/ejabberd-stanza-ack

Comment: Can you guide me how can i develop a custom module. I have no idea about ejabberd just using its built in functionality

Comment: check the links above and try to develop custom module according to your requirement .Befor doing anything try to understand ejabberd hooks and handler.